# Codeigniter rewrite url dynamic subdomain in windows hosting

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, web-config, subdomain

I have this URL:

```
www.mysite.com/welcome/subdir/642marathen/1
```

where,

- `welcome` is a  controller
- `subdir` is a  function
- `642marathen` is a first parameter *(this can be dynamic)*
- `1` is a  second parameter *(this can be dynamic)*

Now, I want a URL like:

```
642marathen.mysite.com
```

How can I use URL rewrite to achieve this?

Comment: where is the second parameter in your URL?

Comment: Second parameter is 1 (it's a daynamic id like category id)

Comment: 1 is in your first URL (as you have it working now), but not in your second URL (as you want it to work), why?

Comment: no sir okai let me clear this.
My Url is : www.mysite.com/welcome/subdir/642marathen/1 this is working fine.
but i want that when i access 
642marathen.mysite.com
it will call : www.mysite.com/welcome/subdir/642marathen/1


actually this all about the dynamic sub domains

Comment: ok but then.. the second parameter (1) should be a constant in your htaccess file, right? otherwise i would expect  1.642marathen.mysite.com or  642marathen.1.mysite.com

Comment: exactly sir...........

Comment: I have added code formatting for readability. And the target url that you want to achieve. Please check if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Now, I want a url like:

instead 642marathen.mysite.com/welcome/subdir/1
, i want 642marathen.mysite.com only